# Access denied when embedding quicksight URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, quicksight-embedding

I am trying to embed an AWS Quicksight dashboard into our application but I am having some trouble with the embed process. The URL has been generated correctly and but I get a permission denied error when I attempt to embed it.

I am able to load the generated URL directly in a new tab but when I attempt to embed it I get a 401 error.

I have whitelisted the domain in the Quicksight console and am accessing the page over HTTPS. The complete test page is shown below.

The following code is what I am using to test embedding. It was taken from an Amazon example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Dashboard</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk/dist/quicksight-embedding-js-sdk.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function embedDashboard() {
                var containerDiv = document.getElementById("dashboardContainer");
                var params = {
                    url: "<link that works in a standalone browser tab>",
                    container: containerDiv,
                    parameters: {
                    },
                    height: "700px",
                    width: "1000px"
                };
                var dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(params);
                dashboard.on('error', function(err) {console.log('dashboard error:', err)});
                dashboard.on('load', function() {});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="embedDashboard()">
        <div id="dashboardContainer"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Amazon sends a 302, followed by a 401. Which results in a frame with the error message "We can't display this page (Not Authorized).

The first request in the image fetches a fresh link from the server and the subsequent two are the framing attempt.

[image: requests]

I would expect that if something was wrong with my authorization then a loading the link in it's own tab would not work. I think the issue must be with the frame but don't know what other options to check beyond the whitelist.

Does anyone have any idea what else I can try?

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @fenrigne123 Yes we were, it turned out to be a blocking of third party cookies in the browser preventing the authentication/redirect from suceeding. Whitelisting the domains sorted it out.